# WinForm ListBox - how to display text from an object?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a piece of code I am working on that someone else started.  They created custom objects (not a collection) and insert these objects into the listbox on the fly.  However, they apparently never did the part where they display the text.  It just shows "Collection" repeatedly in the listbox.  They did not use binding, nor create a collection of these objects in advance, so I don't think I can use DisplayMember.  How do I tell WinForms the field to display?

```
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {

            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.DocumentID  = Guid.Parse (row ["ID"].ToString());
            doc.FileName    = row ["FileName"].ToString();

            // Now add the items to the listbox.  
            lstAttachedDocuments.Items.Add (doc);
        }
```

Comment: override `ToString` in `Document`

Comment: do you have control over the `Document` class? or is it from some API that you use?

Comment: Yes, you can set the `DisplayMember`. You can also build a `List<Document>` and use it as the DataSource. Or use the DataTable as the ListBox.DataSource. Many options.

Comment: There is a document class, but it has nothing it in but 3 properties (DocumentID, FileName, FullPath).

Comment: Can someone supply a simple piece of code that would resolve my problem?  I wrote a simple ToString() method for the custom class, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: " for the custom class" for which custom class?

Comment: For the Document class.

Comment: I found that I can't simple say lstAttachedDocuments.DisplayMember = doc.FileName or lstAttachedDocuments.DisplayMember = doc.ToString()

Comment: I found it.  FormattingEnabled was set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont have control over the Document class where you can override the ToString() method

```
public class Document{

//....        
public override string ToString()
            {
                //Add more properties here if needed 
                return $"{FileName}";
            }
}
```

then just set the lstAttachedDocuments datasource to the datatable

```
lstAttachedDocuments.DataSource = dt;
```

and then the DisplayMember

```
lstAttachedDocuments.DisplayMember = "FileName";
```

Comment: Thank you!  How simple a solution.  I love it.  It did cause a problem where as I update the listbox, old results are not going away, but it's definitely a clean start.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Wait, one more quick question... how do I get the DocumentID from the listbox when an item is clicked?

Comment: Document selectedDocument = (Document)lstAttachedDocuments.SelectedItem;
and now you can display the properties of the selectedDocument in any way or method

Comment: I think I have it.  I just assigned ValueMember to the DocumentID.  I should be able to reference that now.  Again, appreciate the help.